# Angular universal set 404 status code not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

I am out of options at this point. We have an angular 11 website and we need to use Universal for SEO.
We have a 404 page where we redirect if the page is not found.

Problem is that the redirect returns status code 200 instead of 404, so we use Universal to fix this.
I got Universal working and serving the app, but i am not getting it to throw 404 when there is a redirect to 404 component.

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { NgxRequest, NgxResponse } from '@gorniv/ngx-universal';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import * as cookieparser from 'cookie-parser';
import { exit } from 'process';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

// for debug
require('source-map-support').install();

// for tests
const test = process.env['TEST'] === 'true';

// ssr DOM
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
// index from browser build!
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
// for mock global window by domino
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
// mock
global['window'] = win;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
// not implemented property and functions
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
// mock documnet
global['document'] = win.document;
// othres mock
global['CSS'] = null;
// global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global['Prism'] = null;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  // Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
  enableProdMode();

  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
    ? 'index.original.html'
    : 'index';

  // redirects!
  const redirectowww = false;
  const redirectohttps = false;
  const wwwredirecto = true;
  server.use((req, res, next) => {
    // for domain/index.html
    if (req.url === '/index.html') {
      res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname);
    }
 
    // check if it is a secure (https) request
    // if not redirect to the equivalent https url
    if (
      redirectohttps &&
      req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https' &&
      req.hostname !== 'localhost'
    ) {
      // special for robots.txt
      if (req.url === '/robots.txt') {
        next();
        return;
      }
      res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
    }

    // www or not
    if (redirectowww && !req.hostname.startsWith('www.')) {
       res.redirect(301, 'https://www.' + req.hostname + req.url);
    }

    // www or not
    if (wwwredirecto && req.hostname.startsWith('www.')) {
      const host = req.hostname.slice(4, req.hostname.length);
      res.redirect(301, 'https://' + host + req.url);
    }

    // for test
    if (test && req.url === '/test/exit') {
       res.send('exit');
       exit(0);
    }

    next();
  });

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ 
https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModule
    })
 );

 server.set('view engine', 'html');
 server.set('views', distFolder);

 // Example Express Rest API endpoints
 // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
 // Serve static files from /browser
 server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
     maxAge: '1y',
 }),
);

server.get('/404', (req, res) => {
   res.status(404);
   res.render('index', { req });
});

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
 global['navigator'] = { userAgent: req['headers']['user-agent'] } as Navigator;
 const http = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === undefined ? 'http' : req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];

res.render(indexHtml, { req, res, bootstrap: AppServerModule, providers: [
    { 
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
      useValue: req.baseUrl 
    },
    // for http and cookies
    {
      provide: REQUEST,
      useValue: req,
    },
    {
      provide: RESPONSE,
      useValue: res,
    },
    /// for cookie
    {
      provide: NgxRequest,
      useValue: req,
    },
    {
      provide: NgxResponse,
      useValue: res,
    },
    // for absolute path
    {
      provide: 'ORIGIN_URL',
      useValue: `${http}://${req.headers.host}`,
    },
  ],
 });
});

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = 4201;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  // gzip
  server.use(compression());
  // cookies
  server.use(cookieparser());

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

app.browser.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

import { TranslatesBrowserModule } from '@shared/translates/translates-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { InlineStyleModule } from './inline-style/inline-style.module';
import { InlineStyleComponent } from './inline-style/inline-style.component';
import { StateTransferInitializerModule } from '@nguniversal/common';

// the Request object only lives on the server
export function getRequest(): any {
  return { headers: { cookie: document.cookie } };
}

export function getResponse(): any {
  return Response;
}

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, InlineStyleComponent],
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    StateTransferInitializerModule,
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    TranslatesBrowserModule,
    InlineStyleModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: false }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      // The server provides these in main.server
      provide: REQUEST,
      useFactory: getRequest,
    },
    // {
    //   provide: RESPONSE,
    //   useValue: { status: function() {} }
    // },
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
  ],
})
export class AppBrowserModule {}
```

error-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { BaseComponent } from '../base.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-error-page',
    templateUrl: './error-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./error-page.component.scss']
})
export class ErrorPageComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() errorType: number;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response) { 
    super();
  }

    ngOnInit() {
    console.log('here with response', this.response);
    if (!!this.response)
      this.response.status(404);

    this.errorType = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type'));

        if (!this.errorType)
      this.errorType = 404;

    this.loadingService.showHideLoader(false);
  }
}
```

Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '404', component: ErrorPageComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled' });
```

app.server.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { TranslatesServerModule } from '@shared/translates/translates-server';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { InlineStyleComponent } from './inline-style/inline-style.component';
import { InlineStyleModule } from './inline-style/inline-style.module';
import { CookieService, CookieBackendService } from '@gorniv/ngx-universal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // AppModule - FIRST!!!
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    InlineStyleModule,
    TranslatesServerModule
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, InlineStyleComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: CookieService, useClass: CookieBackendService },
  ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'my-app' }),
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "11.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "11.0.3",
    "@gorniv/ngx-universal": "2.2.2",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "8.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/common": "11.0.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "11.0.1",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "9.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.40.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.4",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.5",
    "core-js": "3.8.1",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "fingerprintjs2": "2.1.2",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "node-cache": "5.1.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.3",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.8",
    "save": "2.4.0",
    "toastify-js": "1.9.3",
    "tslib": "2.0.3",
    "vanilla-lazyload": "17.3.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "11.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "11.0.1",
    "@types/chai": "4.2.14",
    "@types/express": "4.17.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "14.14.10",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.1",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "mocha": "8.2.1",
    "nodemon": "2.0.6",
    "npm-delay": "1.0.4",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "prettier-tslint": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.19",
    "ssri": "8.0.0",
    "ts-mocha": "8.0.0",
    "ts-node": "9.1.0",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.0.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2"
}
```

i am at my wits end here, have spend weeks trying to get this to work now without any success

Comment: Is this Fixed.?

Comment: Please help me out for angular 9 404 status code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be in providers, both in server and in the component itself. Here's a shortened example of how I've implemented setting status 404 to the document in one of Universal projects:

**server.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

import { NgxRequest, NgxResponse } from '@gorniv/ngx-universal';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // Do not serve the following routes via Universal
  server.get('/user/**', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(join(distFolder, 'index.html'));
  });

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml,
      {
        req: req,
        res: res,
        providers: [
          {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl
          },
          {
            provide: NgxRequest, useValue: (req)
          },
          {
            provide: NgxResponse, useValue: (res)
          }
        ]
      });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

**page-not-found.component.ts**

```
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, Injector, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-not-found',
  templateUrl: './page-not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-not-found.component.scss']
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId,
    private injector: Injector
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      const response = this.injector.get(RESPONSE);
      response.status(404);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: tried your code exactly as is, still not working

Comment: does the not found component needs to be in its own module?

Comment: in my case there was a lazy loaded module for page-not-found component. but it's not a must. do you have any errors thrown?

Comment: when the app starts its complaining that jquery cannot be run on an empty document, but jquery works all over the site, will try moving it to its own module and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Am also Stuck for this..... please help me out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code